# System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed exeception

Tags: c#, asp.net, plesk, shared-hosting, nreco

I am trying to generate PDF from HTML data using [NReco.PdfGenerator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.PdfGenerator/).

```
public static MemoryStream HtmlToPDFConvert(string html)
{
    HtmlToPdfConverter pdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
    pdfConverter.Size = NReco.PdfGenerator.PageSize.A4;
    var pdfBytes = pdfConverter.GeneratePdf(html);
    var ms = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes);
    return ms;
}
```

Code is working fine in my local machine, but I am getting below error when running code on server (plesk shared hosting).

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.     at MyClass.MyMethod(string arguments)     at b_Submit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)  The action that failed was:  LinkDemand  The type of the first permission that failed was:  System.Security.PermissionSet  The Zone of the assembly that failed was:  MyComputer
```

Looks like the error is because, NReco is trying to generate exe file for wkhtmltopdf but server is not allowing to generate that exe file.

Is there any way to solve this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NReco was trying to generate exe file for wkhtmltopdf but server is not allowing to generate that exe file. So, I am now using [iText](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/) library to generate PDF and it does not required any exe to be generated.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use NReco.PdfGenerator on shared hosting because when you call `GeneratePdf` method wrapper executes wkhtmltopdf.exe with System.Diagnostics.Process API. On most shared hostings usage of this API is prohibited and it is not possible to start another processes from ASP.NET app.

This limitation is mentioned in [NReco.PdfGenerator's FAQ](https://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx#faq) ("Technical limitations").